# Duplicate symbol when compiling C++ on Mac Netbeans 11

Tags: c++, linker, ld, clang++, netbeans-11

I am attempting to compile some code I inherited, but I keep getting errors such as:

```
duplicate symbol _Wox in:
    build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/BOFM.o
    build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/IM.o
```

In total, I am getting 260 of these errors.

For each error, there are 4 files involved, 2 implementation files and their respective header files. The headers contain only variable and function declarations while the implementation files only have function definitions and `#include`'s.

If a variable is used in multiple implementation files, the header for the 'master' (main) file has a normal declaration while all other headers use `extern` in their declarations.

In the following example the variable Wox is not declared in the master header but is included with the `IM.hpp` header, which has a declaration. Both the master and slave implementation files use the same Wox variable.

master header (BOFM.hpp)

```
#ifndef BOFM_HPP
#define BOFM_HPP

double g = 9.80665;
double R = (8.205 * pow(10.0, (-5.0)));
double dLime = 3340.0;
double dDolomite = 3250.0;

... [no Wox declaration]

void initFirstMin();
void calcBOF();
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);

#endif
```

master implementation (BOFM.cpp)

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>

#include "BOFM.hpp"
#include "IM.hpp"
...
void initFirstMin(){
   ...
   Bs.push_back(Wox.at(x - 1).at(2) / Wox.at(x - 1).at(1));
   ...
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   ...
   initFirstMin();
   ...
}
```

slave header (IM.hpp)

```
#ifndef IM_HPP
#define IM_HPP

double MHm;
std::vector<double> WiHm (static_cast<int> (4), 0);
double Sulphur;
...
std::vector< std::vector<double> > Wox;
...
void initST();
void initFT();

#endif
```

slave implementation (IM.cpp)

```
#include <vector>
#include "IM.hpp"

...
void initST()
{
    Wox.push_back({ 33.5, 17.5, 27, 5, 13.5 });
    Wox.push_back({ 31.5, 19, 27, 3.5, 14.5 });
    Wox.push_back({ 29, 20.5, 28, 3, 14.6 });
    Wox.push_back({ 28, 20.5, 32, 3, 14 });
}
...
```

The compiler is running according to C++11. I can provide any missing required details.

Comment: ***Declare*** variables (using the `extern` keyword and without initializers) in header files. ***Define*** variables with initializations in a single source file.

Comment: Also note that this problem is irrelevant about specific standard release of C++, it's a generic C++ issue. So I change the `c++11` tag to the generic `c++` tag.